# Gatling plugin for Jenkins without pom.xml

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, gatling

Has anyone tried to use [gatling plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Gatling+Plugin) for jenkins, but without maven? I don't have maven project, but I generate results using Gatling from terminal (bash script). Using `-rf` switch I change results folder destination to `/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Gatling_test/builds/newest_build/results`, but anyway there is error:

```
Archiving Gatling reports...
ERROR: Publisher com.excilys.ebi.gatling.jenkins.GatlingPublisher aborted due to exception
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not find a Gatling report in results folder.
    at com.excilys.ebi.gatling.jenkins.GatlingPublisher.saveFullReports(GatlingPublisher.java:97)
    at com.excilys.ebi.gatling.jenkins.GatlingPublisher.perform(GatlingPublisher.java:65)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$3.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:36)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:804)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:776)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.post2(Build.java:183)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:726)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1618)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:46)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:247)
Finished: FAILURE
```

Build just run shell script, and post-build action is set to `Track a Gatling load simulation`.
Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think that you should send your results into the workspace of the job, not the job itself.

In [the code](https://github.com/jenkinsci/gatling-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/com/excilys/ebi/gatling/jenkins/GatlingPublisher.java#L65) the plugin looks for results in the workspace of the build.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Perfect! This is the solution. I changed path after `-rf` switch to `/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Gatling_test/workspace/results` and it works :)
Thank you

Comment: Thanks for the tip. You can also use the Jenkins environment variable $WORKSPACE instead of hard coding the projects' name.