# Is Karate-gatling working with Gatling Jenkins Plugin?

Tags: karate

I added the plugin Gatling to jenkins and add it to my job.
But when I run my test on Jenkins I have the following message :
Archiving Gatling reports...
Could not find a Gatling report in results folder.
No newer Gatling reports to archive.

Is Karate-gatling working with Gatling Jenkins Plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest I haven't tried this. It sounds to me that all you need to do is ensure the reports are generated in the folder which the plugin expects.

I thought it should have worked because Karate doesn't try to change any Gatling defaults. If you can do some more investigation and help the community, that would be great.

Actually I think this answer has your solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17919105/143475

Or refer this: https://github.com/gatling/gatling/issues/3091

Comment: Thanks for your answer Peter.
I found the solution by copying gatling results into the workspace of my job.